# Springboot Unable to register client applications to the Eureka server with custom context path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I was able to register the client application in the eureka server when i didnt specify server.servlet.context-path value in eureka server application configuration. But, when i changed the server.servlet.context-path to some value, then unable to register a client application in Eureka server and im always getting an error 404. If someone please have a look and guide me on what im missing that would be of great help. I have found few SO related to this error but mostly they are with old versions of spring boot and i tried few but doesnt help. My spring version is 2.2.6

Please see my configuration below,

Eureka server configuration

```
spring.application.name = eureka-server
server.port = 8761
server.servlet.context-path=/myeureka
eureka.client.register-with-eureka = false
eureka.client.fetch-registry = false
```

Client configuration

```
spring.application.name = client

server.port=8082
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/myeureka/eureka/
```

Exception Details below,

```
14:22:25.566 [restartedMain] INFO  c.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Disable delta property : false
14:22:25.567 [restartedMain] INFO  c.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Single vip registry refresh property : null
14:22:25.660 [restartedMain] INFO  c.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Force full registry fetch : false
14:22:25.661 [restartedMain] INFO  c.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Application is null : false
14:22:25.661 [restartedMain] INFO  c.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Registered Applications size is zero : true
14:22:25.662 [restartedMain] INFO  c.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Application version is -1: true
14:22:25.662 [restartedMain] INFO  c.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
14:22:26.254 [restartedMain] WARN  c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient - Request execution failure with status code 404; retrying on another server if available
14:22:26.259 [restartedMain] ERROR c.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - DiscoveryClient_<Masked here> - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server
com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-1.9.17.jar:1.9.17]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.17.jar:1.9.17]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.9.17.jar:1.9.17]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.9.17.jar:1.9.17]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.17.jar:1.9.17]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1074) [eureka-client-1.9.17.jar:1.9.17]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:988) [eureka-client-1.9.17.jar:1.9.17]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:433) [eureka-client-1.9.17.jar:1.9.17]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:279) [eureka-client-1.9.17.jar:1.9.17]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:275) [eureka-client-1.9.17.jar:1.9.17]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:67) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:324) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) [spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) [spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) [spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) [spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) [spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) [spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:359) [spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:389) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:186) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:356) [spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getTargetObject(EurekaRegistration.java:129) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient(EurekaRegistration.java:117) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:499) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c0a1add4.getEurekaClient(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:38) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.<Masked>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_241]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
14:22:26.262 [restartedMain] WARN  c.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Using default backup registry implementation which does not do anything.
14:22:26.264 [restartedMain] INFO  c.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient - Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 30
14:22:26.277 [restartedMain] INFO  c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator - InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 4
```

Comment: What happens when you hit http://localhost:8761/myeureka/eureka/ directly? Do you get a 404?

Comment: Yes, i got 404 error

Comment: Then your eureka server is not running on that route. Verify that and it would help you fix this issue.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?